# Rotate an image around center

Tags: android

How can I rotate an image around it's center point? This rotates it but also moves it:

```
 Matrix mat = new Matrix();
 mat.postRotate(45);
 Bitmap bMapRotate = Bitmap.createBitmap(dialBM, 0, 0, dialBM.getWidth(),dialBM.getHeight(), mat, true);
dial.setImageBitmap(bMapRotate);
```

I've checked other examples on this site, but they either fail to work or use canvas, I do not wish to use canvas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second and third arguments to postRotate is the x and y pivot point.

```
 mat.postRotate(45, dialBM.getWidth()/2, dialBM.getHeight()/2);
```

Comment: Oh, that is indeed simpler, although I guess it does internally what I suggested.

Comment: This doesn't work. My dial rotates but not around it's center.

Comment: Change the second and third arguments to the location you would like it to rotate around. (`postRotate(degrees, pivotX, pivotY)`)

Comment: I did, I want it to rotate around the dial center which correct me if I am wrong is the width and height divided by 2?

Comment: Yes the center of the image is height/2 and width/2. I suggest opening the image in an editor and finding the exact location you would like it to rotate at.

Comment: Ok, I've made a new image to make sure, 20px x 20px and manually put in mat.postRotate(45, 10, 10); BUT I still get a rotation that is off center.

Comment: Interesting, trying setting filter to false.

Comment: Filter to false does not work. Also, interestingly, changing it to something ridiculous like: mat.postRotate(45, 1000, 1000); has no effect. Any ideas why?

Comment: I'm not able to test anything right now, but try `setRotate()` instead of `postRotate()`.

Comment: Unfortunatley no luck with set rotate

Comment: Last thing I can think of... try `transform.setTranslate(xCenter, yCenter);` then post the rotate.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because your matrix rotates around (0,0), and not the middle of your bitmap. You should declare two additional matrices - one for moving the bitmap's center to (0,0) (shift by -getWidth()/2, -getHeight(2)) and one to move the bitmap's center back to (0,0). Multiply the three matrices, and then the result.